# Delete issues for removed source code files

Tags: java, static-analysis, fortify

Is it possible to delete (instead of marking `removed`) issues from files which are deleted now?

I've tried excluding the files from the Project Translation when scanning, but it didn't help. Now when those files are deleted, I don't want to see their issues in the Fortify project.

BTW I'm using HP Fortify 3.70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that best practices would say:

1. Audit tag as appropriate
2. Add comment that they were removed
3. Suppress the vulnerabilities.

You can do this quickly by "grouping by" source file, multiselecting, then Tag/Comment/Suppress all at one time.

Actually removing vulnerabilities would break the history audit trail.

Comment: Or if the files themselves were deleted, they should show up as removed in the results after a merge. If you don't want to see these, just change the view settings (in Options in AWB or "View Settings" while auditing in SSC) so that you don't see removed issues.